# No module named 'kivy.logger'; 'kivy' is not a package

Tags: python, kivymd

my code:

```
from kivymd.app import  MDApp

class HelloWorld(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return

HelloWorld().run()
```

the error message:

```
C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m kivy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\kivy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivymd.app import  MDApp
  File "C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from kivy.logger import Logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.logger'; 'kivy' is not a package

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in your error message that you have a file called `kivy.py` at `C:\Users\Home\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\kivy.py`.

When you import from `kivy` your python script is treating this file as the import source instead of the installed `kivy` library. Rename this file and it should import from the `kivy` library instead (as long as it's installed).